# failed - "cannot open the connection"

Tags: r

I am trying to read several url files. Does anyone know how to check first if it can open the url and then do something? Sometimes I am getting error (failed="cannot open the connection"). I just want this to skip if it cannot open the connection.

```
urlAdd=paste0(server,siteID,'.dly')
# Reading the whole data in the page
if(url(urlAdd)) {
  tmp <- read.fwf(urlAdd,widths=c(11,4,2,4,rep(c(5,1,1,1),31)))
}
```

But this condition fails.

Comment: the caffeinated answer is good. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115045/how-to-handle-errors-while-reading-xml-files-r/31115268#31115268 for _robustify_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` which returns the value of the expression if it succeeds, and the value of the `error` argument if there is an error. See `?tryCatch`.

This example looks up a bunch of URLs and downloads them. The `tryCatch` will return the result of `readlines` if it is successful, and `NULL` if not. If the result is `NULL` we just `next()` to the next part of the loop.

```
urls <- c('http://google.com', 'http://nonexistent.jfkldasf', 'http://stackoverflow.com')

for (u in urls) {
    # I only put warn=F to avoid the "incomplete final line" warning
    # you put read.fwf or whatever here.
    tmp <- tryCatch(readLines(url(u), warn=F),
                    error = function (e) NULL)
    if (is.null(tmp)) {
        # you might want to put some informative message here.
        next() # skip to the next url.
    }
}
```

Note this will do so on *any* error, not just a "404 not found"-type error. If I typo'd and wrote `tryCatch(raedlines(url(u), warn=F)` (typo on `readLines`) it'd just skip everything as this would also through an error.

---

edit re: comments (`lapply` is being used, where to put data-processing code). Instead of `next()`, just only do your processing if the read succeeds. Put data-processing code after reading-data code. Try something like:

```
lapply(urls,
       function (u) {
           tmp <- tryCatch(read.fwf(...), error = function (e) NULL)
           if (is.null(tmp)) {
               # read failed
               return() # or return whatever you want the failure value to be
           }
           # data processing code goes here.
       })
```

The above returns out of the function (only affects the current element of `lapply`) if the read fails.

Or you could invert it and do something like:

```
lapply(urls,
       function (u) {
           tmp <- tryCatch(read.fwf(...), error = function (e) NULL)
           if (!is.null(tmp)) {
               # read succeeded!
               # data processing code goes here.
           }           
       })
```

which will do the same (it only does your data processing code if the read succeeded, and otherwise skips that whole block of code and returns `NULL`).

Comment: I am using lapply for the looping. Does next() work for lapply also?